# Eval alternative

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, metaprogramming

I have a bazillion controllers in my app, and I was wondering about using some metaprogramming  to make maintenance less of a headache. This works, but it's spiked with danger in the form of eval:

```
  def plural_action(method_name)
    class_name =  self.class.to_s.gsub( %r{^(\w*)Controller} ) {|s| $1 } 
    @title = "#{method_name.to_s.titlecase} of #{class_name}" 
    eval "@q = #{class_name.singularize}.where(:client_id => current_user.client_id).search(params[:q])"
    eval "@#{class_name.downcase} = @q.result(:distinct => true).paginate(:page => params[:page])"
    eval "session[:query] = @#{class_name.downcase}.map(&:id)"
    eval "respond_with(@#{class_name.downcase})" 
  end
```

Can I do this without using eval? I've tinkered with instance_variable_set, send and const_get but no luck so far.

Here's an example of what I'd like the method to eval to.

```
  def index
    @title = "Index of Books" 
    @q = Book.where(:client_id => current_user.client_id).search(params[:q])
    @books = @q.result(:distinct => true).paginate(:page => params[:page])
    session[:query] = @books.map(&:id)
    respond_with(@books)
  end
```

Comment: The [decent_exposure](https://github.com/voxdolo/decent_exposure) gem might get you part of the way there, although it wont solve the problem completely.

Comment: Did you think about using inherited_resource gem to do this all for you?

Comment: Sounds daft, but my heroku slug size is already 77mb due to gem dependencies. I'm trying wherever possible not to add more!

Comment: I think Heroku is going to have to reevaluate the 100mb limit.  My basic Rails 3.1 app is also near 50mb.  I would rather have Heroku fix this than get rid of my gems though.

Comment: I agree. I've recently posted a support ticket to them about it - will add a comment here if I hear back.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's a magnificent method `constantize` which turns a string into the constant (of which class types are an example) it represents. With that in mind, I think you could rewrite your method as:

```
def plural_action(method_name)
    class_name =  self.class.to_s.gsub( %r{^(\w*)Controller} ) {|s| $1 } 
    @title = "#{method_name.to_s.titlecase} of #{class_name}" 
    @q = class_name.singularize.constantize.where(:client_id => current_user.client_id).search(params[:q])
    self.instance_variable_set("@#{class_name.downcase}", @q.result(:distinct => true).paginate(:page => params[:page]))
    session[:query] = self.instance_variable_get("@#{class_name.downcase}").map(&:id)
    respond_with(self.instance_variable_get("@#{class_name.downcase}"))
end
```

Comment: Ooh, that is handy. However, I need to be able to set instance variables too. I'll edit my question with the desired outcome. Thanks!

Comment: @snowangel - it looks like `instance_variable_set` _should_ do what you want. I'll edit my answer - but you say you've tried it?

Comment: Well, I tried it, but probably did it wrong, so your thoughts would be incredibly helpful.

Answer (score 0):

```
def plural_action(method_name)
    class_name =  self.class.to_s.gsub( %r{^(\w*)Controller} ) {|s| $1 } 
    @title = "#{method_name.to_s.titlecase} of #{class_name}" 
    @q = class_name.singularize.constantize.where(:client_id => current_user.client_id).search(params[:q])
    instance_variable_set class_name.downcase, @q.result(:distinct => true).paginate(:page => params[:page])
    session[:query] = @q_result.map(&:id)
    respond_with(@q_result)
end
```

Comment: This threw the error "`books' is not allowed as an instance variable name". Chowlett's version worked though. Many thanks for the reply though!.